# How to make web security for more than one app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

the problem is there are 3 web projects developed using ASP.Net MVC,they have the same users, so i need to do separate project for the Security to make the 3 project consume it through web API.
how can i use the identity framework for that problem or what is the best practice ?

Comment: *how can i use the identity framework for that problem* by writting some code

Comment: Probably use IdentityServer or another SSO solution

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your problem correctly you want the authentication for all 3 Projects at one place.
Challenges that you may face

1.all projects might have their own entry page after user is authenticated.Figure that out first.

2.Using Oauth you can implement your own authentication service Provider and there you pass bearer token when user gets authenticated which means you are giving access to your user to enter any of your 3 proj.

3.all of your projects should have a Owin middleware which will redirect to your security Project while user comes for the first time.
In future you can implement refresh token in your security Project also.